# How to send text in UTF-8 using Indy TIdTCPServer in c++ builder

Tags: sockets, java-me, character-encoding, indy10

My client j2me application reading text input stream using UTF-8

```
reader = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8");
```

and my server when gets connected sends text using this statement

```
AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(cxMemo1->Text,TEncoding::UTF8);
```

but result text showing weird characters like ?????????????????????????? ?????????????

Where I'm doing wrong?

also when i tried to load from utf-8 encoding data file in such a way

```
AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteFile("c:\\fids.xml");
```

it's all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Indy 10 completely supports UTF-8 encoding. I've myself worked with it's TIdFTP component & successfully uploaded Unicode text files. From what I can make of it:

1. Your connection/transfer type is set to `ftASCII` rather than `ftBinary`.
2. Your J2ME applet/Host platform does not suport UTF-8

Comment: I made connection using the following code `String URL="socket://"+ServerIP+":"+ServerPort;  socket=(StreamConnection)Connector.open(URL);`

Comment: I know that these powerfull components do a lot more than I think of but the problem is i am doing smth wrong here.

Comment: **Edit**: I'd like to change my original post, Indy is still in development regarding how it handles Unicode efficiently (courtesy Remy). You might want to try using Write().

Comment: TransferType only applies to the `TIdFTP` component, not the `TIdTCPServer` component.

Comment: Anyway @nbaztec I am using LWUIT! Does it support UTF-8 ? I googled and haven't found yet!

Answer (score 0):

'?' characters occur when data is going through a Unicode-to-Ansi conversion to an Ansi charset that does not support the Unicode characters being converted.

What version of C++Builder are you using?  In versions prior to CB2009, you should tell Indy the encoding of the AnsiString data that you are passing in.  Indy defaults to ASCII (ie: `TIdTextEncoding::ASCII`) for most String-based operation.  That can be overridden when needed, either with optional `AAnsiEncoding` parameters, the `TIdIOHandler::DefAnsiEncoding` property, or the global `Idglobal::GIdDefaultAnsiEncoding` setting.  If you do not specify the correct encoding, the AnsiString data may not be converted to Unicode correctly before then being converted to UTF-8.  For example:

```
AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(cxMemo1->Text, TIdTextEncoding_UTF8, TTIdTextEncoding_Default);
```

Or:

```
AContext->Connection->IOHandler->DefAnsiEncoding = TIdTextEncoding_Default;
AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(cxMemo1->Text, TIdTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

You can optionally also use the `TIdIOHandler::DefStringEncoding` property if you do not want to specify the UTF-8 encoding on every call:

```
AContext->Connection->IOHandler->DefStringEncoding = TIdTextEncoding_UTF8;
AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(cxMemo1->Text);
```

Now, with that said, the fact that `WriteFile()` is also sending data that J2ME is not handling correctly tells me that Indy is not the root of the issue.  WriteFile() simply dups the raw file data as-is to the connection without any interpretation at all.  If you send a UTF-8 encoded file, then UTF-8 encoded octets will be sent to J2ME.

I suggest you use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to verify the data that Indy is sending.  That will tell you for sure whether Indy is really at fault or not.

*PS: notice in the examples above that I use Indy's `TIdTextEncoding` macros instead of `TEncoding` directly.  This is because Indy's TIdTextEncoding logic works around some bugs in Embarcadero's `TEncoding` classes.  Also, we're going to phase out direct support for `TEncoding` in Indy 11 and expand on `TIdTextEncoding` so Indy has more control than Embarcadero offers.

Comment: Hi @Remy I'm using C++ Builder 2010 !

Comment: Also this way doesn't helping too `try {
  int b=AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadByte();
  result->Items->Add(b);

  //AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteFile("c:\\fids.xml");
  AContext->Connection->IOHandler->DefStringEncoding = TIdTextEncoding::UTF8;
  AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(cxMemo1->Text);
  AContext->Connection->Disconnect();

 }
 catch(Exception & e) {
  //ShowMessage(e.ToString());
  AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
 }`

Comment: All you have done is add a call to `IOHandler->ReadByte()`, you have not changed anything else regarding how you send data back to J2ME.  You still need to isolate the root cause of the problem.  Did you do what I suggested and verify the raw transmitted data yet?  In any case, I know for a fact that `Write(UnicodeString, TIdTextEncoding::UTF8)` works fine in CB2010, because that is the version I use myself.  BTW, reading the `cxMemo1->Text` property directly in a `TIdTCPServer` event handler like you are is not thread-safe, so that may be a factor by itself.

Comment: I used portable Wireshark but can't enter right filter to show only desired packets sent, then I assigned socks but my capture was mixed up I think.

Comment: you know what IP/Port your server is listening on, you can filter for that.  Or simply locate a single packet that you recognize the data for, then right-click on it and choose "Follow Stream" to see all packets just for that connection.